# Find in IE not looking in DIV set with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a page with 3 DIV's on them, one with a header, one with a selection-list and the third will get filled with data once something is selected in the selection-list.
When something is selected, code like

```
document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="' + fieldsPage + '" style="width:70%;height:90%" ></object>';
```

is executed, filling the DIV with the contents of another (generated) page.
I can view the page fine in Chrome and IE, but...

...when I search for something, Chrome finds it even in the DIV filled through innerHTML, but IE doesn't.
IE seems to only search in the header and selection-list DIV's.
Any suggestions to get IE to search the whole page as well?

Comment: When you say "Chrome finds it", are you referring to the built in "Ctrl+F" (or `Cmd+F`) keyboard shortcut to find a string?

Comment: Yes, CTRL+F showing the searchbox in upper-right in Chrome (extra bar upper-left in IE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var node = document.createElement ("object");
node.type = "text/html";
node.data = fieldsPage;
node.style.width = "70%";
node.style.height= "90%";
document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("fields").appendChild(node);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Nope, same problem. Works fine in Chrome, but not in IE